# Google maps android get place

Tags: java, android

I want to start google maps when i click on button and then the user will choose place and I will get the user address name and longitude and latitude that the user choosed.

I searched alot over here and on google and didnt find an answer.

I want something like this:

```
Button getLocation= (Button) footer.findViewById(R.id.getLocation);
getLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //start google maps and let the user choose a place, then return to this
        //activity and get the latitude and longitude and the name of place
        //that was chosen
    }
});
```

this is the map fragment that i use:

```
 <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="150dp" />
```

Comment: so what u want to do is: YOUR APP-(click)-Google Maps App-(return value)-YOUR APP ?

Comment: yes,exactly, can you help me please?

Comment: I think you'd better to launch a MapView(which is GoogleMap based, apparently) from your main activity and let user to use the map marker to choose the location, then return the value back to your main activity. For your original idea you may launch Google Maps App from your app however I doubt if Google Maps App can return value back to your app.

Comment: hi, i am not sure that i understand you, how can i return back the value to the main Activity? can you please post this code? thanks alot

Comment: maybe if it's immposible, can i search address in the fragment of google maps in my activity and then get the coordinates and name of this place?

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html Then implement it as one your activity or fragment, then you can retrieve the location when user drops the marker

Comment: hi, i allready read this tutorial , the user supply the coordinates to google maps and only show this place on google maps nothin about retrieving the location, am i miss something? thanks alot     static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
  static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);

Comment: Ok i'm posting the code snippet i'm using, please let me know if you've got further questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`coords[]` is a global `double` array variable.

Basically the idea is to show the map within a map fragment inside the activity.

I set a listener to the marker, so when user move the marker, it will be triggered and handled by the `handler`.

`R.id.map` is the fragment layout if you followed [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) to set up.

```
    public class Activity extends FragmentActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

                .......

            //Set up map view
            map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            mHandler = new LocationHandler(this); 
                .......

        OnMarkerDragListener markerDragListener = new OnMarkerDragListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
                    // Called when the marker drag is started

                }

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                    // Called when the marker is dropped down.
                    coords[0] = marker.getPosition().latitude;
                    coords[1] = marker.getPosition().longitude;
                    RestoreUIwithSavedLocation(coords);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Pin Dropped at: " + coords[0] + ", " + coords[1]);
                }

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

                }
            };

            map.setOnMarkerDragListener(markerDragListener);
        }
    }

    private void RestoreUIwithSavedLocation(double[] coordsArray) {
        Message.obtain(mHandler, LOAD_COORD, coordsArray).sendToTarget();
    }

    // Write a inner class
    static class LocationHandler extends Handler {
        WeakReference<Activity> mActivity;

        public LocationHandler(Activity activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
        }

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Activity contextActivity = mActivity.get();
            switch ((int)msg.what) {

            case LOAD_COORD:
                map.clear();
                double[] coordArray = (double[])msg.obj;
                Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(coordArray[0], coordArray[1])));
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(coordArray[0], coordArray[1]), 18));
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18), 2000, null);
                marker.setDraggable(true);
                String s = Double.toString(coordArray[0]) + ", " + Double.toString(coordArray[1]);              
                contextActivity.text_location.setText(s);
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more parameters of the Google Map API, you can refer to this: [Google Maps Android API v2 - GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener)

Comment: thanks alot, i will try it, i see that you got the coordinates, how can i also get the name of this place?with getTitle()? also what type is handler (mHandler )? and what is my class need to extends?

Comment: also, what is the value of LOAD_COORD constant?

Comment: `LOAD_COORD` is just a string constant used to distinguish the message. You can see how i passed the `LOAD_COORD` in the method `RestoreUIwithSavedLocation(double[] coordsArray)`

Comment: You just need to write a inner class `static class LocationHandler extends Handler` in your activity class.

Comment: I updated my answer with several lines to help you better understanding :-)

Comment: hi, thanks alot! i updated my answer with the definition of the google maps element in my layout, so how do i need to findViewByID this element with the line that you wrote:                map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
  or with this line:           map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
  ?

Comment: Please check http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html this tutorial has a complete code that u need. What u'll need to do next is to add a marker listener (like the code in my answer) and handle the drag. Good luck